Arduino ESP32 Cam
I kept receiving this reponse
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
Even though i already tried to click the flash and reset button of my ESP32 Cam Module
I tried to follow the guide from online resources and any other and i expect to sent a link or API.
